# How to Bind Delta<T> in web api2 odata 3 controller

Tags: json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata, model-binding

So I'm building out new dataservices, and figured I'd use web api odata. So I added a controller to my project using the scaffolding to generate actions for my entity framework model classes. Everything worked great until I tried the generated put or patch methods. The guid Id from the url binds, but no matter what I try I can't bind the Delta variable. It's always null. After a day of googling i can't find anything newer than about 2011 and those solutions don't work. Does anybody know how to get these to bind?

method signature

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Guid key, Delta<AttachmentProposal> patch)
```

my web api config

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<AttachmentProposal>("AttachmentProposals");
    builder.EntitySet<AttachmentAction>("AttachmentActions");  
    config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

my model is something like

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public DateTime createDate { get;set; }
public virtual HashSet<AttachmentActions> {get; set;}
```

if it makes any difference i always try to send up json. typical request body's i've tried are like

```
{ name: 'some name' }
```

or

```
{ every: 'value', single: 'value', property: 'value', on: 'value', my: 'value' model: 'value' }
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out the answer by making a console app with a reference to the service and watching the traffic. If anybody else is having this problem try adding odata.type: "what ever the type of your object is" to the json in the request